# Trouble with configuring networking devices

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth

I have a dual boot system. With Windows in the other partition. My wifi-hotspot and bluetooth works perfectly there but in ubuntu i face this issue where in hotspot creation says that there is only one wifi-card thus i cannot remain connected to the main wifi and run the hotspot at the same time (which I very well do in Windows). The blue tooth gives the issue where it says no bluetooth card enabled.
Pls help me get this right.
on Checking just realised ubuntu cannot recognize my bluetooth device and the network card used is:(03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
)

Comment: What are the wifi and bluetooth chipset/card you are using ?

Comment: I am using hp 4440s hp laptop with the inbuilt wifi and bluetooth card. I do not know how to check the same.

Comment: Edit your post to add output of `lspci|grep 'Network\|Ethernet'` command and `lsusb|grep bluetooth`

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
angkirat@angkirat-HP-ProBook-4440s:~$ lsusb|grep bluetooth
<noo/p>                                                                                                                                       is that it....

Comment: The last I knew, for Ubuntu you need 2 wifi cards to do what you want and bluetooth may never work as Ralink doesn't want to release info on this chipset